# Nim cannot do check regex object with failed captured group

Tags: nim-lang

How to check one of nre object member with a failing captured group such:

```
  if m.get.captures[1] == "" : echo "group 1 is empty"
```

still fails, results in

```
nre.nim(342)            
Error: unhandled exception: Group '1' was not captured [IndexDefect]
```

as m is nre type returned of

`m = find( "foo", r"(f)o(?:(u)|(o))" )`

as we can see the group 0 and 2 succeed, and not the 1

Please help out solving

Comment: What is your regex?

Comment: Group 1 would be the `(u)`, which doesn't match if the input is `foo`. If you switch the input to `fou`, group 1 should match, but group 2 not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if the index is in `captureBounds` as follows:

```
import std / nre
let m = find("foo", re"(f)o(?:(u)|(o))")
for i in 0 .. 2:
 if i notIn m.get.captureBounds:
    echo "group ", i, " is empty"
 else:
    echo m.get.captures[i]
# f
# group 1 is empty
# o
```

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3QiN)

**note:** how did I get there (not having used much or anything `nre`)? I followed the source code (clicking from documentation but you could also have started from the error message) and the line that gave it away is: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/7994556f3804c217035c44b453a3feec64405758/lib/impure/nre.nim#L314